# Вывести информацию из базы данных в listview или другим способом (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

Cтолкнулся с проблемой 2 дня назад с выводом базы данных MySQL "phpmyadmin" в приложении. В базе данных на локальном сервере храниться text и id, photo в формате BIN-BLOB. В долгих поисках вывода такого рода информации в GridView я натыкался на все возможные варианты, которые к сожалению мне не подходили. Остановившись на этом варианте я пишу сюда.

```
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=couseuiop");
        conn.Open();
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM news"; // Из какой таблицы нужен вывод 
        MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmd, conn);
        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new MySqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("news"); // В скобках указываем название таблицы
        dataAdp.Fill(dt);
        StudentsGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; // Сам вывод 
        conn.Close();
```

Код в XAML:

```
Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <DataGrid   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="642" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="StudentsGrid">

    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы подобного рода результат который я на данный момент имею:[image: фото имеющего результата]
Был хотя  бы приблизительно в таком варианте :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть вариант кода декодирования изображения в формате bin-blob (png)

```
MySqlCommand command_image = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE id = 535", dataBase.GetConnection());
        dataBase.openConBd();
        MySqlDataReader reader_image = command_image.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader_image.Read())
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])reader_image[1];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.StreamSource = ms;
            bmp.EndInit();
            imageAdd.Source = bmp;

        }
        dataBase.CloseConBd();
```

Буду очень рад в любой оказанной помощи. Я только начал изучать WPF & базы данных, многие описанные вами алгоритмы  могут оказаться сложными и хотелось бы попросить описать возможные варианты решение более доступным языком, для меня и других пользователей) Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` может биндиться прямо к массиву байт, преобразование в картинку произойдет автоматически. Чтобы сделать то что вам надо, не нужна `DataGrid`.

```xml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding img}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Если нужно выбирать элемент из коллеции, то подойдет `ListBox`, просто замените `ItemsControl` на `ListBox` и все продолжит работать. Если выбор не нужен, а нужна только прокрутка, то можно `ItemsControl` снаружи завернуть в `ScrollViewer`.

Кстати, привязки данных можно делать и на верхнем уровне, а не только внутри коллекций.

Допустим, вы весь код пишете в классе окна и про MVVM не в курсе, тогда нужно изменить класс окна вот так

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DataTable _items; // не используйте _items в других местах кода
    public DataTable Items    // вместо этого используйте именно Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Items)));
        }
    }

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

А в разметке написать вот так

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

Тогда в вашем методе чтения из базы достаточно будет написать вот так.

```
Items = dt;
```

При чем в коде вы можете переприсваивать `Items` где угодно и сколько угодно раз. `ItemsControl` сам подхватит изменения.

Всё, никакой возни с битмапами и прочими мучениями в C# с интерфейсом не требуется. Учитесь пользоваться привязками данных, WPF заточен под них и многое умееет делать сам.

Comment: Как пишут в этих самых интернетах - "категорически плюсую"!